# matplotlib: filter to produce a antialiased image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a low resolution image that I want to scale up and display in a figure.  As you might expect, the image looks a bit pixelated, so I would like to do some filtering on it.  Matplotlib has `filternorm` and `filterrad` as filtering options in `plt.imshow()`, but they don't seem to do anything.  The best I have been able to do is change the interpolation method to `bicubic`.  I would like something where I can smoothly adjust the degree of filtering.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this using Matplotlib?  I imagine I could import PIL or something from Scipy, but I'd like to avoid that.

Here is the raw image at it's native resolution (340x240)

[image: native rez]

Here is the matplotlib code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('path/on/my/computer')
im_obj = plt.imshow(im, interpolation = 'bicubic', resample = True)
plt.savefig('im_bicubic.png')
```

and here is the resulting png

[image: scaled]

Comment: The documentation seems to imply they only do anything for `interpolation` in  'sinc', 'lanczos' or 'blackman' and if your input is integers.

Comment: @tcaswell  According to my reading of the documentation, `filterrad` only has an impact when `interpolation` is 'sinc', 'lanczos' or 'blackman'.  However, it looks like `filternorm` should work with any type of interpolation and it should work with integers.  I tried several `filternorm` values and I tried 'since' and 'lanczos', but nothing seemed to make a difference. I googled for the antigrain documentation, but the AGG website is down.

Comment: mpl ships with a full version of AGG (they relicesed from bsd -> gpl at some point so mpl has a copy of the last BSD version + local modifications)

Comment: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/R-I-P-Maxim-Shemanarev-td42567.html  It may be the case that the main agg site has been sadly orphaned.